# Formatting Variable as Date (mm/dd)

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a script that identifies the date range of the previous month (Cell G9 is today's date).  It is working; however, the output is formatting the date much differently than I am intending.  The [J36] output is "01/08" when it should be "08/01" and the [J37] output is "6:11:37 AM" (interpretting it as a time), when it should be "08/31".  I am only coding for the output in particular cells because I want to see that it is working.  However, it is the variable I want to format, not the cell.  I'm going to be using the startdate and enddate variable in future code and those variables on their own won't be visable in any cells.

I attempted to use the format(startdate,mm/dd), but I got an overflow error.

Here is my script:

```
Dim thismonth As Integer
    thismonth = Month(Sheet1.[G9])
Dim startdate As Date
Dim enddate As Date


Select Case thismonth
    Case 1
        startdate = 12 / 1
        enddate = 12 / 31
    Case 2
        startdate = 1 / 1
        enddate = 1 / 31
    Case 3
        startdate = 2 / 1
        enddate = 2 / 28
    Case 4
        startdate = 3 / 1
        enddate = 3 / 31
    Case 5
        startdate = 4 / 1
        enddate = 4 / 30
    Case 6
        startdate = 5 / 1
        enddate = 5 / 31
    Case 7
        startdate = 6 / 1
        enddate = 6 / 30
    Case 8
        startdate = 7 / 1
        enddate = 7 / 31
    Case 9
        startdate = 8 / 1
        enddate = 8 / 31
    Case 10
        startdate = 9 / 1
        enddate = 9 / 31
    Case 11
        startdate = 10 / 1
        enddate = 10 / 31
    Case 12
        startdate = 11 / 1
        enddate = 11 / 30
End Select

Sheet1.[J36] = startdate
Sheet1.[J37] = enddate
```

Comment: Quick question - instead of all the `Select Case` stuff, if `thismonth` is a number you could just do `startdate = thismonth - 1 / 1`, no? (With the exception that `If thisMonth = 1 then startdate = 12`).  Also, @trincot makes a great point. You need to change how you set the start/end date. Also FYI you can use [`EOMONTH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-eomonth-method-excel) for a quick way to get the last day of any month.

Comment: Be aware that `8 / 31` is not a date expression, but  the division of 8 by 31.

Comment: @BruceWayne That is true, and how I originally started, but I specifically need to identify the first and last day of the previous month.

Comment: You could use `ThisMonthYear = (Right(Date, 7)) ` or `ThisMonth = Left((Right(Date, 7)), 2)`

Comment: FYI A date literal would look like `#9/20/2017#`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a much simpler solution:

```
Dim startDate as Date
Dim endDate as Date

startDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EOMONTH(Sheet1.[G9],-2) + 1
endDate = Application.WorksheetFunction.EOMONTH(Sheet1.[G9],-1)
```

You can get rid of VBA altogether and write this worksheet formula directly in `J36` and `J37` respectively.

J36: `=EOMONTH(G9,-2)+1`

J37: `=EOMONTH(G9,-1)`

Comment: Ok, I have to laugh because that was so, so much more simple, and worked so much better! Thanks for your help!! :)

Comment: It said I have to wait a few minutes before I can do that, but I definitely will.  Also, can you explain the "...,-2)+1" in startDate rather than "...-1)" that appears in endDate

Comment: Nevermind, just looked up the EOMONTH function and got it figured out.  Thanks!